# Magento 2 product attributes hidden in product edit page?

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, product-edit

[image: hidden attribute]

I have a problem with magento 2. I created 2 attribute: show time countdown and show product on homepage. It work properly on localhost and other sites and magento versions. But I get an issue. All attribute hidden on edit page.

**Update:**

[image]
This is my 'Top' attribute set. It seems group product detail with my attribute is showing and group general is hidden.

Comment: check 'Top' attribute_set have your two attributes.

Comment: I have checked 'Top' attribute_set. It had my attributes. But other attributes as price, name, .... don't show.

Comment: Did you try re-indexing?

Answer (score 0):

I have found error for this issue. In 'Top' attribute_set, I have General group and Product detail group. In Product edit, It don't show general group.